# Switching between nested UIScrollViews during drag gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nested, scrollview

I have a tableview, within a table view.  I want the parent table view to move only when the child table view's vertical content offset is at zero.

The difficulty I am having with this specification is that it is further complicated by the fact that the responder should change **during** a drag gesture.  So effectively, the child table view will scroll up until the childTableView.contentOffset.y <= 0, at which point the parent table view begins scrolling and the child table view stops scrolling.

I have tried a complex arrangement of scroll view callbacks from both table view's, to juggle when the responsibility should change.  At which point I move the pointer for the active gesture.  But this requires removing your finger and re-applying your finger, which is no good.

I have tried subclassing the child table view, setting up a datasource (viewForHitTest:) over-riding 'hitTest:withEvent' and returning the parent table view conditionally.  But this requires a decision before scrolling commences, and I need to know which direction user is scrolling before I decide which view should be the responder.

I have tried disabling delayedContentTouches and working with 'shouldBeginTouches', but again, I can't establish which direction the user will be scrolling.

I have also tried to over-ride the UIResponder touchesBegan:withEvent touchesMoved:withEvent etc but the documentation states that this approach is only relevant when you want to implement fine grained control of forwarding gestures between sibling subviews.

I have watched Apple's 'exploring scroll views in iOS 7' WWDC 2013 and it's equivalent in WWDC 2014, to no avail. The nested scroll view discussion, with excellent demo is not applicable in this case because they use a transform adjustment as an illusion, which they can reset quite easily.

Does anyone have any creative ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It`s difficult to help you without code. But if you want an idea and a place to test. Both tableView are scrollView, If you use the scrollViewDidScroll: methods delegate. You can see who call this method, with is its position, and use or not. I think playing with this method you might find some solution.

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 // Who scroll
 if ([scrollView isEqual:self.sonTableView] && scrollView.contentOffset.y != 0)
 {
     self.sonTableView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
     // Father nothing (OR what you want.
 }
 else if ([scrollView isEqual:self.sonTableView] && scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
 {
    // don't disable at first, because we abort the gesture. (In other delegate you can disable)
   // self.sonTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    // We stop the scroll in the son by code: 
    self.sonTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
    // And here we star moving the father. 
    self.father.contentOffset = CGPointMake(fatherIni.x + (-scrollview.contentOffset.x),fatherIni.y + (-scrollview.contentOffset.y));


 }
 else if ([scrollView isEqual:self.father] && // Other conditon)
 {
    // do what you want
 }
 else if (// other condiction)
 {
    // wake up the son.
 }

 }
```

Other options is disable both, and use a UIPanGesture in a clear view just above both a put the contentoffset according a them position and this pan gesture.

Comment: ..."I have tried a complex arrangement of scroll view callbacks from both table view's, to juggle when the responsibility should change. At which point I move the pointer for the active gesture. But this requires removing your finger and re-applying your finger, which is no good."...scrollEnabled also stops the scroll and you need to lift you finger and re-apply your finger to engage scroll.

Comment: @robdashnash I know what you said, I have more info in my answer. It's difficult to help you without cede to test.